# Flutter & VSCode: Gradle Build Error

Tags: android, gradle, visual-studio-code, flutter

I have recently setup VSCode and Flutter on my Mac and created a new project.

I can build it to the iOS Simulator and devices, however when attempting to run on the Android simulator I get the following build error when it fails to run:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Exit code 1 from: /Users/Username/Desktop/Dart:Flutter Test/test3/android/gradlew -v:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Exited (sigterm)
```

In case it is worth noting I have Android Studio 3.0 installed (previous to setting this up).

Comment: (Pro-tip: we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.)

Comment: gradel folder at the root level inside android project is missing, grade/gradlewrapper.jar and properties file is missing

Comment: @silentsudo Doesn't seem to be the case. wrapper.jar and .properties files are present in mention folder.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my issue by removing a forward slash '/' from a folder name my project was kept in. That / is translated into a ':' and it doesn't like it!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I noticed that the folder which contained my flutter project had space in its name. So I renamed and removed the space and my issue got resolved.